# Solve the equation $\frac{1}{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^{2k}(x)} = 8$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the equation $\dfrac{1}{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^{2k}(x)} = 8$ where $k$ is an integer and $x$ is a real number.

**Attempt**

We have that $\dfrac{1}{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^{2k}(x)} = \dfrac{\sin^{2k}(x)+\cos^{2k}(x)}{\cos^{2k}(x)\sin^{2k}(x)} = 8 \implies \sin^{2k}(x)+\cos^{2k}(x) - 8\cos^{2k}(x)\sin^{2k}(x) = 0.$ I get stuck here and am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: for $k>4$, you should find that the minimum of $\frac{1}{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^{2k}(x)}$ is greater than $8$. For $k\le 0$, the maximum is at most $2$. So you only have to consider $k=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: How did you get the maximums and minimums?

Comment: Sorry, the minimum is greater than $8$ for $k>2$, so you actually only need to check $k=1$ and $k=2$.

Comment: If you know calculus, you can just find the extrema by taking the derivative of the expression, although it may be a bit tedious that way. Alternatively, using the AM-GM inequality to get that $\frac{1}{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^{2k}(x)}\ge\frac{2}{|\sin^{k}(x)\cos^{k}(x)|} = \frac{2*2^{k}}{|2\sin{x}\cos{x}|^k} = \frac{2^{k+1}}{|\sin{2x}|}\ge 2^{k+1}$. So if $k>2$, then the expression is greater than $2^{2+1} = 8$.

Comment: @JohnRyan Take the first and second derivatives.

Comment: Did you need to take the absolute value?

Comment: @JohnRyan $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$8=\dfrac1{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\dfrac1{\cos^{2k}(x)} \geq \dfrac{2}{\left\vert\sin^k(x)\cos^k(x)\right\vert} = \dfrac{2^{k+1}}{\left\vert\sin^k(2x)\right\vert} \geq 2^{k+1}$$
Hence, we have $k+1 \leq 3 \implies k \leq 2$.

If $k=0$, we have $\dfrac1{\sin^{2k}(x)}+\dfrac1{\cos^{2k}(x)}=2$.

If $k < 0$, we have $$\sin^{-2k}(x) + \cos^{-2k}(x) \leq \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$$
Hence, the only options are $k=1$ and $k=2$.

If $k=2$, we see that
$$8 = \dfrac1{\sin^4(x)} + \dfrac1{\cos^4(x)} \geq \dfrac8{\sin^2(2x)} \implies \sin^2(2x) \geq 1 \implies \sin^2(2x) = 1$$

This implies that
$$2x = n\pi + \dfrac{\pi}2 \implies x = \dfrac{n\pi}2 + \dfrac{\pi}4$$

When $k=1$, we have that
$$\dfrac1{\sin^2(x)} + \dfrac1{\cos^2(x)} = \dfrac1{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)} = \dfrac4{\sin^2(2x)} = 8$$
Hence,
$$\sin^2(2x) = \dfrac12 \implies 2x = n\pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}4 \implies x = \dfrac{n\pi}2 \pm \dfrac{\pi}8$$

Comment: how did you conclude if $k<0$ that $$\sin^{-2k}(x) + \cos^{-2k}(x) \leq \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1?$$

Comment: @JohnRyan $0\le \sin^2 x\le 1$, therefore $\left(\sin^2 x\right)^{-k}\le \sin^2 x$ for all $k\le -1$ (same for $\cos$), because $f(x)=a^x$ is non-increasing in $(0,+\infty)$ when $0\le a\le 1$.

Comment: @user236182 Isn't $\dfrac{1}{0.5} > 0.5$ though, for example?

Comment: @JohnRyan It's unrelated. $-k\ge 1$, not $-k\le -1$.

Comment: I believe Leg should've stated that the solution set is the union of solutions.